# Which is a better MondoDB schema design?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

In general, which is a better schema and why? I run into this same problem over and over again, and it seems to be mixed online with which is better.

The first schema has a single document for a location ID with a nested menu:

```
{
    locationID: "xyz",
    menu: [{item: "a", price: 1.0}, {item: "b", price: 2.0}...]
}
```

The second schema has multiple documents for a given location ID

```
{
    locationID: "xyz",
    item: "a",
    price: 1.0
},
{
    locationID: "xyz",
    item: "b",
    price: 2.0
}
```

The first schema seems like it's faster and doesn't duplicate the location ID so uses slightly less memory. The second schema seems slower since it has to gather the documents (perhaps it's indexed alphabetically though?), but it's so much easier to modify.

Is there a "firm" answer or guideline on this?

Answer (score 1):

For the actual data you showed above, I would opt for the first design.  The first design allows all menu items for a single location to be stored in, and retrieved from, a single Mongo document.  As you pointed out, this would probably be faster than when using the second more normalized design.

As to when you might use the second version, consider the case where the menu item metadata be relatively large.  For example, let's say that you wanted to store a 10KB image for each menu item.  MongoDB has a limit of 16MB as the maximum size for a single BSON document.  For locations with several hundred menu items, you might not be able to fit all menu items and their metadata info a single document.  In such a case, the first option might be out and you would be forced to use the second option (or something else).